# If no OU path entered set default instead

Tags: if-statement, null, powershell-3.0, ou

New to PS and need some help with `$null` values, I want to ask the user to set a OU path but if the user enters nothing then it will revert to the default which is in the if statement.

```
$OU = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the new users OU path"

if($null -eq $OU)
{
$OU="CN=Users,DC=de,DC=ing,DC=kus,DC=tb"
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Is it PHP? Tag your question with appropriate language.

Comment: Noted, its PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the `$null` with `""` as I was detecting a string.

```
$OU = Read-Host "Enter the new users OU path"

if ($OU -eq "")
{

    $OU = "CN=Users,DC=**,DC=***,DC=***,DC=**"

}

else
{

}
```